# How to do django pagination more efficiently

Tags: django, pagination

I am using the django default pagination but I am concerned about its efficiency.I have 3000+ objects stored in my database and I display 15 each page.So every time I go to the next page it seems to me I have do database query again in my views.My code in views.py is just like the code given in the docs of Django.Here is my code:

```
all_words=Word.objects.all()
    user=request.user
    wordlist = []
    for word in all_words:
        taged_word = FlagWord.objects.filter(word = word,user = user)
        if taged_word :
            usertag = True
        else:
            usertag = False
        wordlist.append({'word':word,'usertag':usertag})
    number = Word.objects.count()
    paginator = Paginator(wordlist,15)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page','1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1

    try:
        listpage = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage,InvaildPage):
        listpage = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render_to_response('GRETemplate/wordbank.html',{'words':listpage,'user':user,'number':number})
```

It's like I have my wordlist ready for the first time but I have to do it over and over again when i request for another page.Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Thanks.G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ideally cache the results of `Word.objects.all()` so the system doesn't hit your db everytime.

However, I think your loop could be simplified a little:

*Warning: I haven't tested it.*

Suppose your Word model is:

```
class Word(models.Model):
   the_word = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

First, you get all the flagged words that belong to the current user:

```
fw = FlagWord.objects.filter(user = user)
if fw.count():
    if fw.word_set.count():
      wordlist.append(
                   dict(('word':obj.the_word,'usertag':True)
                       for obj in fw.word_set.all())
```

Finally, filter the word list with the other words that didn't match. I've expanded the code since it contains lots of brackets.

```
wordlist.append(dict(
                      ('word':obj.the_word,'usertag':False)
                      for obj in
                         Word.objects.exclude(
                           the_word__in=fw.values_list('word__the_word',flat=True)
                         )
                     )
               )
```

Comment: How do you compare your loop with mime? Is it the `for word in all_words:
        taged_word = FlagWord.objects.filter(word = word,user = user)` part that is expansive?Also how to cache the result?

Comment: Your loop checks each word in the table against linked objects in FlagWord, by fetching it from the DB. Mine does the reverse, it only searches those words that have any linked FlagWords, then filters the others at the SQL level.

For caching, see the [caching documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/). You would probably want the [per view cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache)

Comment: haha.I used your method by (only changed a little) and found out the speed fasted a lot!Wow,algorithm really matters a lot.Many thanks.